# Daemon can still print to stdout?

Tags: ruby, daemon

I'm writing a daemon in Ruby 1.8.7 (i.e., no Process.daemon) using a double-fork + setsid:

```
exit if fork
Process.setsid
exit if fork
```

After all of this, I still, for some reason, seem to be able to print out to stdout.  From everything I've read, the daemon process should not have a controlling terminal, and writes to stdout should not do anything.  However, if I follow up the above with a:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

"Hello world" is printed to the screen.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I believe this is expected. Calling `Process.setsid` does not close any open file descriptors, you will need to manually reopen them with `/dev/null`, e.g.:

```
io = File.open("/dev/null", "w+")

exit if fork
Process.setsid
exit if fork

$stdin.reopen(io)
$stdout.reopen(io)
$stderr.reopen(io)
```

Or, if you care about the output, you could reopen stdout and stderr with log files.

I would also recommend changing the working directory to `/` to avoid the daemon running in a non-existent directory:

```
Dir.chdir("/")
```